# PMD Security - Apex Suggest Using Named Cred

Tags: apex, security, pmd

Getting `Suggest named credentials for authentication` error in my PMD script.

```
http http = new http();
        httpRequest request = new httpRequest();
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', accessTokenValue);
        request.setBody(jsonReplacedString);
        httpResponse res = http.send(request);
```

getting error in this line  `request.setHeader('Authorization', accessTokenValue);`

**Note:** I have another Method which will do an HTTP call to get the access token, It's the dynamic value not hardcoded/stored anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This PMD error suggesting you to use NamedCredential instead of setting the auth header in the code (because NamedCredential is more secure). But, if you have a valid use case of not using NamedCredential, you could use the PMD suppress warnings annotation on the class/ method (or may be custom ruleset).

Comment: `Authorization` is the dynamic value, Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: If you need to continue with the existing code and suppress this error, refer to https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html & https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html. But, if you want to use named credential, then could you provide some additional details?

Comment: Created named Credentials ` request.setEndpoint('callout:PayPal_Create_Payment');`  and setting a Authorization Value in Header `request.setHeader('Authorization', accessTokenValue);`  accessTokenValue --> Access token is the dynamic value which we generated each time with unique value Ex: `Bearer A21AAH5GQmTn-v0CMgXuN6vTW6wv-q3iVWYHMb3vkoZ9ZUuFfwPygzGh88g4ZlBLPHxV7A_YczkXuD2-uAlCSeH1noSjZx9wA`

Comment: You don't need to pass the token via auth header explicitly in your code. Instead, enable Generate Authorization Header (under callout options) in the Named Credential. That should take care of the auth.

Comment: You Mean, we need to create `Auth. Provider` with `key` and` Secret` and in Named Credentials we need to provide `Authentication Provider` as Auth Provider Name right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. `key` & `secret` will need to fetched from the provider site.