# How to use a Named Credential within an Auth. Provider Plugin?

Tags: namedcredentials, auth-provider, pmd, authproviderpluginclass

I'm currently working on an Apex Auth Provider Plugin, and I've encountered a PMD code scan error with the following message:

> Suggest named credentials for authentication. Rule: Security-ApexSuggestUsingNamedCred

The challenge I'm facing is that, to create the required Named Credential, I need to have an Auth Provider already created that is specific to that Named Credential. This leads to a circular dependency where creating one necessitates the creation of the other, and so on.

How you typically addres this PMD rule in such scenarios. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Is PMD complaining about the callout? Presumably the callout from your custom auth provider would be done via named credential with another, hopefully out of the box auth provider.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PMD Security - Apex Suggest Using Named Cred](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/317612/pmd-security-apex-suggest-using-named-cred)